# How to change position of menu bar in joomla website?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i'm trying to make website. new to joomla framework.. I don't know how to use joomla

Please help me :)

How to change position of menu bar

[image: yellow mark]

to yellow mark?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

- First check if your template uses some framework, in some cases you can change the
   menu position from here, check this in:

  **Extensions** > **Templates** > **Your Template**.
- If you don't have this option, go to **Extensions** > **Modules**, find here your menu module,
   inside you can select the template position of your choice.
- Also you can check the available positions in your template, enable the option **Preview**
   **Module Positions** in:

  **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Templates**

  From here add in the URL something like: yoursite.com/**?tp=1**

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give in the joomla backend > modules your menu module any position, (like menu) and then you print it in your template file with:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="none"/>
```